# Generating PDF from CRM 2015 Online edition

Tags: pdf, crm

Using a plug-in (or workflow) in CRM 2015 Online, we would like to:

- generate a PDF (possibly from HTML string)
- attach it to an Email Activity

Anyone has had any experience with this?
Help/advices welcome.

Thanks,

Frank M.

Comment: I am not aware of any out of the box functionality to achieve this. We have to depend strongly on .NET classes to achieve this. iTextSharp is a reusable dll which can help you on this. Sorry, I dont have any url to share with you.